# Run command with variable as other user

Tags: powershell

I am currently trying to build the following scirpt to post-install the MS Store on users.
My problem is that I have to run the first part as admin and the second part as the local user and I can't find a solution for it.

```
# As Admin
Clear-Variable NAMES
Clear-Variable NAME
Clear-Variable PackageFullName

$msg = "Geben sie hier ihre persönlichen Logindaten ein"
$Credential = Get-Credential -Message $msg

$NAMES = @(
        "WindowsStore"
        "Photos"
        "WindowsCalculator"
        )

foreach ($NAME in $NAMES) {
    echo "installing $NAME"
    $PackageFullName = Get-Appxpackage -Allusers -Name *$NAME | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PackageFullName
    #As User
    echo "$PackageFullName"
    Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\$PackageFullName\AppxManifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode
}
```

Comment: You will have to run the per-computer part as administrator and then run the per-user part as each user. (Not sure what else I can say.)

Comment: it would be great if you could do something like linxu `sudu -u username command`

Comment: You can elevate a process but not without causing a confirmation prompt. (This is by design.)

Comment: how do i do that for a command? the prom would not be a problem for me @Bill_Stewart

Comment: You should be able to find that answer by using a search phrase such as "start command elevated powershell" or something similar.